# Redis connection lost on Vert.x 3.9.4

Tags: java, redis, vert.x

After upgrading the `vertx-redis-client` to version `3.9.4` according to  [Vert.x documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/#_using_vert_x_redis)

The connection code was needed to be updated to conform the newer version.
The code based on the example from the documentation above and looks like this:

```
Redis.createClient(vertx, redisOptions).connect(onConnect -> {
    if (onConnect.succeeded()) {
        RedisConnection client = onConnect.result();
        RedisAPI redis = RedisAPI.api(client);
        vertx.getOrCreateContext().put("redis", redis);
    }
});
```

But after an hour (more or less) I'm getting a connection lost with following error stack trace:

```
io.vertx.redis.client.impl.ConnectionManager lambda$static$0 - Unhandled Error
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException 
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.newClosedChannelException(AbstractChannel.java:957)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:865) 
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1367) 
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717) 
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764) 
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790) 
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758) 
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.write(ConnectionBase.java:124) 
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.writeToChannel(ConnectionBase.java:205) 
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.writeMessage(NetSocketImpl.java:130) 
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.write(NetSocketImpl.java:174) 
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.write(NetSocketImpl.java:168) 
at io.vertx.redis.client.impl.RedisConnectionImpl.lambda$send$1(RedisConnectionImpl.java:136) 
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:366) 
at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$executeAsync$0(EventLoopContext.java:38) 
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) 
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) 
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497) 
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) 
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) 
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening?
Or any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your connection is idle for a long period, Redis server might close the connection. There are couple of ways to resolve this. Something similar is explained in this [issue](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/issues/227)

1. Add fixed periodic dummy command (PING) so the connection doesn't get closed.

   ```
   Redis.createClient(vertx, new RedisOptions()).connect(onConnect -> {
       if (onConnect.succeeded()) {
           RedisConnection client = onConnect.result();
           RedisAPI redis = RedisAPI.api(client);
           vertx.getOrCreateContext().put("redis", redis);

           vertx.setPeriodic(30 * 1000, handler -> {
               redis.ping(new ArrayList<>(), result -> {
                   if (result.failed()) {
                       System.out.println("Error " + result.cause().getMessage());
                   }
               });
           });
       }
   });
   ```
2. Add periodic task that will obtain and replace your connection.

   ```
   final AtomicReference<RedisConnection> vertxConnection = new AtomicReference<>();
   private void refreshConnection(Redis client, RedisConnection fallback) {
       // get a connection
       client.connect()
         .onFailure(err -> {
           // maybe log, don't change the current connection
           System.out.println("connect failed: " + err.getMessage());
           vertx.setTimer(5000L, t -> refreshConnection(client, fallback));
         })
         .onSuccess(conn -> {
           // swap old with new
           System.out.println("connect swapped: " + (conn != null ? conn.hashCode() : null));
           final RedisConnection old = vertxConnection.getAndSet(conn);
           vertx.setTimer(5000L, t -> refreshConnection(client, old));
           // the fallback isn't needed anymore
           if (fallback != null) {
             fallback.close();
           }
         });
     }
   // create client
   Redis client = Redis.createClient(vertx, redisOptions);

   // get a connection
   refreshConnection(client, null);
   ```
3. Add exception handler to refresh connection when this happens, good example can be found in official docs: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/#_implementing_reconnect_on_error

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I will check it